# jekyll/knitr: automatically regen rmd AND --watch

Tags: r, jekyll, rstudio, knitr

I'm struggling getting knitr and jekyll to play nicely. I want to automatically regenerate my site, recompiling RMDs, if an RMD changes (handled by `servr`) **or** anything that would trigger a usual rebuild (as in `jekyll serve --watch`).

At the moment I'm use `servr::jekyll()` which automatically regenerates my site any time I modify an RMD - that's great.

However, if I modify just an ordinary MD file (that would usually trigger a rebuild in `jekyll serve --watch`), the site is not rebuilt.

If I try to pass `--watch` e.g.

```
servr::jekyll(command='jekyll serve --watch')
# or
servr::jekyll(command='jekyll build --watch')
```

then:

- with `jekyll serve --watch`, it looks like the site gets regenerated every time I change an MD or RMD file, but the RMDs are not recompiled - jekyll will update MDs if they've changed and serve them, but not recompile an RMD.
- with `jekyll build --watch`, the site isn't served (I guess this is not surprising, though even with `serve=T` it does not serve), and updating behaviour appears to be as with `serve --watch` - MDs are updated but RMDs are not recompiled.
- if I do this in RStudio I can't return back to the prompt - I get the dialog that tries to get me to force quit and eventually the session crashes. I then have to find the jekyll process that is still running and `kill` it.

I guess this is because with `--watch` the call to jekyll doesn't return, so you never get back to R for `servr` to do its own watching? Even with `daemon=TRUE`, `servr` doesn't seem to re-knit the RMDs.

**So my question is, how can I get (can I get?):**

- normal site regeneration as per `jekyll serve --watch` behaviour, **and**
- automatic RMD re-compilation as per `servr::jekyll()` ?

I'm using jekyll 2.4.0 at the moment.

Comment: Good question. I'm afraid you will have to file a feature request, and chances are I won't have time to work on it unless someone brings a pull request :)

Answer (score -1):

For now, if you run `jekyll build --watch` in a separate terminal, they work concurrently. Not an ideal solution, but good enough in the meantime.